# Flutter - Fatal Exception: java.lang.LinkageError

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, admob

I've a Flutter app project and just for some users (7% of my user base) the app crash and Play Store is reporting the following **error** on android devices:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: 
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcpq.zza (zzcpq.java:44)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzevk.zza (zzevk.java:365)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeke.zzN (zzeke.java:58)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeke.zze (zzeke.java:6)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbhd.zzg (zzbhd.java:203)
      at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd (BaseAdView.java:6)
      at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.FlutterBannerAd.load (FlutterBannerAd.java:60)
      at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.onMethodCall (GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.java:737)
      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage (MethodChannel.java:17)
      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler (DartMessenger.java:18)
      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0 (DartMessenger.java:20)
      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger (DartMessenger.java)
      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run (-.java:12)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7397)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:935)​
```

It seems an **admob related** issue because I noted the error:

```
at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.FlutterBannerAd.load(FlutterBannerAd.java:60)
```

About adMob on **pubspec.yaml** I use:

```
  google_mobile_ads : 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/SuaMusica/googleads-mobile-flutter.git
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads
      ref: feature/suamusica
```

This is my **android/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        // jcenter()
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        // }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        // jcenter()
        // maven {
        //     url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        // }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

// subprojects {
//     project.configurations.all {
//         resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
//            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
//                     && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
//                 details.useVersion "1.0.1"
//             }
//         }
//     }
// }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Flutter version 2.10.5 stable**

**Android Studio Bumblebee**

Where can be the issue?

Thank you.

Comment: There is an already open issue on GitHub. You can follow along there https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/471